# Python sqlite3 checking if age matches a birth date from table

Tags: python, sql, function, sqlite

So today I started learning sql in python 3 using sqlite3 but nothing too advanced yet, I have a table with these values: username, name, gender, birth date (String, example: 1/5/2001), email, password. in one of the functions i need to create the function gets an age (int, example: 52), and i need to return all the right rows where the birth date matches the age, now this is what i have, (self.tbl_name = the table's name)

```
def get_by_age(self, age):

    self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {self.tbl_name} WHERE ='{age}'")
    return self.cursor.fetchall()
```

but the problem is i don't know what im supposed to put after the WHERE and before the = to test if the age matches the birth date, can anyone help me?

Here's a similar function i made but instead of the same age it needs to be the same gender:

```
def get_by_gender(self, gender):

    self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {self.tbl_name} WHERE gender='{gender}'")
    return self.cursor.fetchall()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT strftime('%Y', datetime('now'))
returns you 2021, then you can subtract your value and make a SELECT for the year you're looking. If you need also month and day you can use '%m/%d/%Y' instead of only %Y

Comment: I don't understand how I get the age from the birth date... isn't what you suggested just giving me the current date?